# Parallel reading from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, parallel-processing

I was looking through dozens of articles, but couldn't find a solution.

Here is the logic :

I have a Winform (VS2010) application, that needs to read data from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express table `A`, process some calculations and store in a different table `B`.

I want to use parallel `ForEach` in order to shorten execution time (otherwise the calculation + SQL process takes days.....)

I have to read from SQL, because the database has over 5 million rows, each read returns a few hundreds rows.

Lists are defined as :

```
BindingList<ItemsClass> etqM = new BindingList<ItemsClass>();
BindingList<ItemsClass> etqC = new BindingList<ItemsClass>();
```

The parallel execution :

```
Parallel.ForEach(etqC, cv => {
            readData(ref etqM, "tableA", "WHERE ID LIKE '" + cv.Name + "%'");
            IList<ItemsClass> eResults = etqM.OrderBy(f => f.ID).ToList();

            foreach (ItemsClass R in eResults)
            {
                //calculations comes here

                etqM[rID] = R;
            }

            Parallel.ForEach(etqM, r => {
                // part 2 of calculations comes here
                }
            });
            exportList(etqM, "tableB", true);
        });
```

The SQL Read function :
The function gets a List, Table name + conditions for the SQL
read from SQL the records, and transform them to the List format.

```
public void readData<T>(ref BindingList<T> etqList, string tableName, string conditions)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

        etqList.Clear();            
        openConn(myConnection);
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;

        try
        {
            int totalResults;
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + tableName + " " + conditions;
            totalResults = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            if (totalResults > 0)
            {
                myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " " + conditions;
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                etqList = ConvertTo<T>(convertReaderToDT(myReader));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        finally
        {
            try { myReader.Close(); }
            catch { }
        }
        closeConn(myConnection);
    }
```

The SQL export function : this function exports the given list to the table name.

```
private void exportListToSql<T>(IEnumerable<T> etqList, string tableName)
{
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        openConn(myConnection);

        try
        {
            actionTotalCount++;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);
            dt = ToDataTable(etqList);//List Name
            var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(myConnection,
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                null
                );
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = BATCH_SIZE;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {  }
        finally { closeConn(myConnection); }
    }
```

SQL `openConn` and `closeConn` :

```
void openConn(SqlConnection myConnection)
{
        if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) return;
        myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DB_NAME + ";Initial Catalog=APPDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=120;Asynchronous Processing=true;";

        try { myConnection.Open(); actionTotalCount++; }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}

void closeConn(SqlConnection myConnection)
{
        if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Fetching || myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Executing || myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting) return;
        try { myConnection.Dispose(); }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

The problem is : once I execute, I get this message :

> *ExecuteScalar requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is closed.*

This message arrives for all threads, except the first one.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Offtopic: in `readData` you shall close connection in `finally{}` block

Comment: Try out creating connection once and just share across all workers as an input parameter of `readData()` method

Comment: What is the purpose of checking the connection state in `openConn`? `openConn` seems to be called right after creating a `new SqlConnection`. How could it ever be already opened?

Comment: I've tried creating the connection once, but then - in the 'Parallel.ForEach' method it fails with this error message : 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first'.

Comment: @MikeTwo - True, I added it in a previous version, because it seemed I was trying to open a previously opened connection. In this version it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not in the SQL, but the calculations.
Since the List was defined outside the 'Parallel.Foreach', it was accesses by different threads simultaneously, causing a crash.

Once I changed the code as followed, all worked excellent :

```
Parallel.ForEach(etqC, cv => {

        BindingList<ItemsClass> etqM = new BindingList<ItemsClass>();

        readData(ref etqM, "tableA", "WHERE ID LIKE '" + cv.Name + "%'");
        IList<ItemsClass> eResults = etqM.OrderBy(f => f.ID).ToList();

        foreach (ItemsClass R in eResults)
        {
            //calculations comes here

            etqM[rID] = R;
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(etqM, r => {
            // part 2 of calculations comes here
            }
        });
        exportList(etqM, "tableB", true);
    });
```